# Why route table filling happens in first request of MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

For a MVC 5 application, when I debug the solution, then only on first request, break point hits the RouteConfig class, next request on wards, it's not filling the route table again.

Question, where the routing table stored, how it will match on second request?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RouteTable` is implemented as a [singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton). In ASP.NET (or MVC), a singleton's lifetime lasts until the application pool is recycled.

```
namespace System.Web.Routing
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    [TypeForwardedFrom("System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")]
    public class RouteTable
    {
        private static RouteCollection _instance = new RouteCollection();

        public static RouteCollection Routes
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So all web requests will use the same instance of the `RouteTable`, first, second, or otherwise.

The `RouteTable` is automatically repopulated when the application pool recycles because it is initialized within the `Application.Start` event (usually in `Global.asax`). This event only fires 1 time when the application first starts (or when the application pool recycles).